# What's the meaning of every part of a bash prompt?

Tags: bash

i'm very new to mac world, and i'm using bash doing some work.
But I'm not clear about the bash command line. It's so different from cmd.

```
yb_server:~ Aaron$
```

above is the command line when i start a terminal.
what's the meaning of yb_server?( I used to remember it's originally macintosh, why
it's changing to yb_server, how can i recover?)

what does ~ mean?
what does $ mean?

Comment: `~` is a shorthand for your home directory `/Users/Aaron`.  `yb_server` is what the machine thinks its hostname is. If you execute the command `hostname`, it should print that value, or `hostname -f` for the fully qualified hostname. Welcome to the world of real shells (not win CMD) :)

Comment: If you change the working directory like `cd /Library`, the prompt should change to reflect the directory, something like `yb_server:/Library Aaron$` It is there to show you where you are.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not saying `echo $PS1` to see what the prompt is.

Answer (score 3):

`yb_server` is your computer.

`:` is an arbitrary delimiter.

`~` is your home directory (the current directory).

`Aaron` is you.

`$` is "Speak to me, master!" But it is effectively an arbitrary delimiter.

The whole thing is your *prompt*. Google "bash prompt" for lots of info. Its format is totally up to you. Say `echo $PS1` to find out what the format is now. The default is:

```
\h:\W \u\$
```

Learning what those symbols mean is left as an exercise for the reader!

Comment: And for some ideas on how to customize your prompt: http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/697cu/bash_users_what_do_you_have_for_your_ps1/

Comment: Note: you can change the prompt to be anything you want.  My prompt in bash is \[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\u@\h:\w\$ (default in ubuntu), and in zsh is (%{%}%~%{%})
%n@%{%}%m%{%} [%!]%{%}$%{%}  (with a line break in it), which has some color as well.